# Laravel formbuilder how can i get accept and multiple attributes into the element

Tags: laravel-5

I use http://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/ and i want some extra attributes for type `file`

How can achieve that?

Try:

```
->add('image',
    'file',
    [
        'multiple' => true,
        'accept' =>"image/jpg, image/gif",
        'label' => 'Upload your image'
    ])
```

result:

```
<input class="form-control" name="image" id="image" type="file">
```

I want:

```
<input class="form-control" name="image" id="image" type="file" accept="image/jpg, image/gif" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, use `attr array`:

```
->add('image',
    'file',
    [
        'attr' =>[
            'accept'=>"image/jpg, image/giff",
            'multiple' => true
        ],
        'label' => 'Upload your image'
    ])
```